# Initialize method is not working in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to create a Tattoo app for android where you can take a picture but ran into an error with a method and don't know how to solve this error. I've tried to add different using directives or assemblies but that didn't work.

I tried to use this method:
`object p = await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();`
`PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium;`
`CompressionQuality = 40;`
`Name = "icon.png";`
`Directory = "sample";`

but it showed this error and is not working: "object" doesn't contain a definition for "initialize", and couldn't find any initialize expanding method, that accepts an argument of type "object" (maybe there's missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using nuget [Xam.Plugin.Media](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media)?

If yes, you can check the MediaPlugin project website [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) for more information.

If you want to take a photo, you can refer to the following code:

```
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        Directory = "Sample",
        Name = "test.jpg"
    });

    if (file == null)
        return;

    await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        return stream;
    }); 
};
```

And you can also check the full sample here： [MediaPlugin/samples/](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/tree/master/samples).